# Does a spell exist that makes a targeted object desirable to others?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, content-identification

I'm looking for a *Pathfinder* spell, but I don't even know if the spell I'm thinking of even exists.

Basic premise of the spell is that the object which the spell is cast on has an aura of desirability for anyone who failed their save (most likely will). So whatever the spell is cast on should become something that someone really really wants.

So if the desired (heh) spell doesn't exist, I would like to actually make the spell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact effect of the [*Sympathy*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sympathy/) spell, which is ported over without reworking from 3.5:

> You cause an object or location to emanate magical vibrations that attract either a specific kind of intelligent creature or creatures of a particular alignment, as defined by you. The particular kind of creature to be affected must be named specifically. A creature subtype is not specific enough. Likewise, the specific alignment must be named.
>
> Creatures of the specified kind or alignment feel elated and pleased to be in the area or desire to touch or possess the object. The compulsion to stay in the area or touch the object is overpowering. If the save is successful, the creature is released from the enchantment, but a subsequent save must be made 1d6 x 10 minutes later. If this save fails, the affected creature attempts to return to the area or object.

Answer (score 4):

[Beguiling Gift](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/beguilingGift.html#beguiling-gift) is pretty much exactly what you're looking for, although it is single-target only:

> You offer an object to an adjacent creature, and entice it into using or consuming the proffered item. If the target fails its Will save, it immediately takes the offered object, dropping an already held object if necessary. On its next turn, it consumes or dons the object, as appropriate for the item in question. For example, an apple would be eaten, a potion consumed, a ring put on a finger, and a sword wielded in a free hand. If the target is physically unable to accept the object, the spell fails. The subject is under no obligation to continue consuming or using the item once the spell's duration has expired, although it may find a cursed item difficult to be rid of.

It's available to Bards and Witches.

Comment: That was exactly the spell, but doesnt do quite what I was hoping for, so its a great starting point. Thank you so much.